# 'b' in mechanical equation of Dc motor?

Tags: dc-motor

I am trying to study/learn mathematical modelling of a DC motor
 i came across an equation which is known as the mechanical equation for an armature-controlled DC motor

I have understood other parameters in this equation but i am confused by the highlighted "b" term , what is meant by it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The b represent the drag/viscous coefficient of the motor

http://www.pitt.edu/~qiw4/Academic/MEMS1082/DCmotors.pdf

> **2.2 The mechanical equations** 
>   Let us now deal with the mechanical representation of the motor. It has been shown in Section 1.2 that the motor exerts a torque, while supplied by voltages on the stator and on the rotor. This torque acts on the mechanical structure, which is characterized by the rotor inertia J and the viscous friction coefficient F. It has also to be taken into account that

Also:

[Viscous damping in BLDC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/256903/viscous-damping-in-bldc/257054#257054)

[DC motor differential equation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/325607/dc-motor-differential-equation/325965#325965)

Comment: is ''b'' the same thing viscous friction coefficient"F"  ??

Comment: Yes it is. If you look at the placement of the variable and the intent of the equation it is producing the same effect: subtraction of a torque which is proportional to rotor velocity